# Insights on approaching fare calculations

Tags: c, loops, fee

Basically I'm attempting a question on how to compute fee. However, my code is extremely long. I ended up using a heck tons of 'if' and 'else' for my code. I was wondering if there is any better way on approaching this question.

I initially attempted to use loops to keep stacking the fee but I face a problem when my time cross the critical juncture. I added time to TimeIn along with my fees, but as it crosses the 7am mark, I need to reset it back to 7am so that my fees will be charge properly. And that was when I gave up when my code became very long too.

Eg. loop adds from 0630 to 0730, fees are properly increased, the first 30 minutes of 0700 will be skipped and fees are wrongly charged.

The question I attempted:

Mr. Wu has been going to work every day by taxi for many years. However, the taxi fare has been increasing rather quickly in recent years. Therefore, he is considering driving to work instead.
One of the costs for driving is the parking fee. The parking rates of the car park at Mr. Wu’s workplace are as shown in the table below.

```
                 Weekday              Saturday                      Sunday 
4am ~ 7am        $2.00 per hour       $2.50 per hour                 $5
7am ~ 6pm        $1.20 per 30 minute  $1.50 per 30 minutes           per
6pm ~ midnight   $5.00 per entry      $7.00 per entry                entry

Special note:
1. The car park opens at 4am and closes at midnight. All vehicles must leave 
by midnight.
2. There is a grace period of 10 minutes on any day (i.e., it is completely 
free to park for 10 minutes or less regardless of day and time.)
3. There is a 10% surcharge for parking more than 10 hours on a weekday and 
20% for Saturday. There is no surcharge for Sunday.
4. There is an additional $3.00 fee for exiting after 10pm on any day. 
(Surcharge is not applicable on this fee.)
```

Your program should read in one integer, which is an integer between 1 and 7
representing the day of the week (1 being Monday and 7 being Sunday). It should also
read in two numbers representing the time-in and time-out in 24-hour format. It
should then calculate and display the parking fee (with two decimal places).
You may assume that the inputs are valid (i.e., the day is within the specified range,
both time-in and time-out are between 4am and midnight in 24-hour format, and timeout
is no earlier than time-in).

My extremely long code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double computeFee(int, int, int);

int main(void){
int day, timeIn, timeOut;
scanf("%d %d %d", &day, &timeIn, &timeOut);
printf("Enter day: %d\n", day);
printf("Enter time-in: %d\n", timeIn);
printf("Enter time-out: %d\n", timeOut);
printf("Parking fee is $%.2lf\n", computeFee(day, timeIn, timeOut));
return 0;
}

double computeFee(int day, int timeIn, int timeOut){
double fee = 0;
double TimeIn, TimeOut;

TimeIn = 60*(floor(timeIn/100)) + (timeIn%100);
TimeOut = (60*(floor(timeOut/100)) + (timeOut%100));
if((day>=1)&&(day<=5)){
    if(TimeIn<420){
        if(TimeOut<420){
            fee += 2*ceil((TimeOut - TimeIn)/60);
        }
        else{
            fee += 6;
            if(TimeOut>=1080){
                fee += 31.4;
            }
            else{
                fee += 1.2*ceil((TimeOut - 420)/30);
            }
        }
    }
    if(TimeIn>=420){
        if(TimeIn>=1080){
            fee = 5;
        }
        else{
            if(TimeOut>=1080){
                fee += (1.2*ceil((1080 - TimeIn)/30) + 5);
            }
            else{
                fee += (1.2*ceil((TimeOut - TimeIn)/30));
            }
        }
    }
    if((TimeOut-TimeIn)>=600){
        fee *= 1.1;
    }

}
if(day == 6){
    if(TimeIn<420){
        if(TimeOut<420){
            fee += (2.5*ceil((TimeOut - TimeIn)/60));
        }
        else{
            fee += 7.5;
            if(TimeOut>=1080){
                fee += 40;
            }
            else{
                fee += (1.5*ceil((TimeOut - 420)/30));
            }
        }
    }
    if(TimeIn>=420){
        if(TimeIn>=1080){
            fee = 7;
        }
        else{
            if(TimeOut>=1080){
                fee += (1.5*ceil((1080 - TimeIn)/30) + 7);
            }
            else{
                fee += (1.5*ceil((TimeOut - TimeIn)/30));
            }
        }
    }
    if((TimeOut-TimeIn)>=600){
        fee *= 1.2;
    }

}
if(day == 7){
    fee = 5;
}
if((timeOut/100)>=22){
    fee += 3;
}
if((timeOut - timeIn)<=10){
    fee = 0;
}
return fee;
}
```

Examples on how fees are calculated:

```
Example 1: Tuesday, 4:29am to 7:50am.
• 4:29am to 7am is charged as 3 1-hour slots: $2.00 * 3 = $6.00
• 7am to 7:50am is charged as 2 30-minute slots: $1.20 * 2 = $2.40
• Total fee = $6.00 + $2.40 = $8.40

Example 2: Saturday, 7:01am to 7:49pm.
• 7:01am to 6pm is charged as 22 30-minute slots: $1.50 * 22 = $33.00
• 6pm to 7:49pm is charged as one entry: $7.00
• 20% Surcharge for parking more than 10 hours: ($33.00 + $7.00) * 20% = 
 $8.00
• Total fee = $33.00 + $7.00 + $8.00 = $48.00

Example 3: Sunday, 3pm to 10:01pm.
• 3pm to 10:01pm is charged as one entry: $5.00
• Additional fee for exiting after 10pm: $3.00
• Total fee = $5.00 + $3.00 = $8.00

Example 4: Thursday, 11:49pm to 11:59pm.
• Grace period
• Total fee = $0.00

Example 5: Monday, 12pm to 10:01pm.
• 12pm to 6pm is charged as 12 30-minute slots: $1.20 * 12 = $14.40
• 6pm to 10:01pm is charged as one entry: $5.00
• 10% Surcharge for parking more than 10 hours: ($14.40 + $5.00) * 10% = 
$1.94
• Additional fee for exiting after 10pm: $3.00
• Total fee = $14.40 + $5.00 + $1.94 + $3.00 = $24.34
```

Thanks for reading my long question. And thanks in advance for the help.

note: I havent learn arrays and anything beyond that. Only learn loops and selection statement so far(reading K&R programming tutorial, until chapter 17, using Online GeekforGeek as compiler). However, I will still greatly appreciate solutions using other methods.

Comment: In general, one of the alternatives to coding a bunch of conditionals is using lookup tables (typically implemented in C via arrays).  This problem is structured to make that tricky, but it is by no means impossible.

Comment: The rules need some clarification. For the “$2 per hour” rate, what is charged for 15 minutes? $.50 because it is a quarter of an hour or $2 because charges are always in whole units of hours? If car is parked for the last 10 minutes of 4am-7am and the first 20 minutes of 7am-6pm, is it charged four half an hour at the first rate, half an hour at the second rate, or proportional 10 minutes at the first and 20 at the second? If charges are proportional, then fractions can occur with them and with the surcharges. Are they rounded up, to nearest, or down? If to nearest, how are ties broken?

Comment: If there are fractions in the charge from 4am-7am and in the charge for 7am-6pm, are they added and then rounded, or rounded separately and then added?

Comment: The fees are charge part thereof, so if you parked from 7am to 7.15am you will be charge for half an hour.

Comment: If car is parked for the last 10 minutes of 4am-7am and the first 20 minutes of 7am-6pm, it will be charged an hour rate, followed by the next half an hour rate.

Comment: As such, there will be no fractions even with the surcharges